# org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('x' (code 120)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries

Tags: json

*I was trying to print the below String which i was taking from file.

`{"error_msg":null,"channel":0x0,"api_version":"3.4","request_type":"authorize_capture","server_mode":"TEST","auth_result":{"response_code":0x6,"MOP":"VISA","source":"NUL","source_response_code":"   ","terminal_number":"12345","transaction_number":0x38224,"auth_code":"06","avs_response":" ","fraud_response":"0","security_code_response":" "}}`

I am using the below code to do a pretty print

`Object json = mapper.readValue(line, Object.class);

String ss = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json);`

I am getting the following error. Please help me to resolve this issue

`Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('x' (code 120)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries`

Comment: If you use a [JSON online parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) you will see what's wrong -- JSON does not permit numeric values with the notation `0x0`.  Whatever code produced that "JSON" string did not do it right.

Comment: **I am getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token x**

Comment: Yes, because the JSON is invalid.  Where are you getting that JSON??

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax. You will see that a "number" cannot be expressed in hex notation.